# c# sub class of mainwindow cannot handle processes

Tags: c#, class, process, workflow-foundation, visual-studio-2015

So this class that's in my main wpf cant do process5, im trying to run this class at the same time as the main window.cs, is that possible?
main issue: class1 not letting me initiate private processes like in mainwindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApplication3
{

private object process5;

class Class1
{




    process5 = Process.Start("notepad.exe");

}
}
```

But in the main window, process 1-4 can:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private object process1;
    private object process2;
    private object process3;
    private object process4;



    public MainWindow()
    {

        /*
        Task.Run(() => process1 = Process.Start("notepad.exe"));
        Task.Run(() => process2 = Process.Start("calc.exe"));
        Task.Run(() => process3 = Process.Start("c:\\windows\\explorer.exe"));
        Task.Run(() => process4 = Process.Start("C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Audition CC\\Adobe Audition CC.exe"));
        */

        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => process1 = Process.Start("notepad.exe"));
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => process2 = Process.Start("calc.exe"));
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => process3 = Process.Start("c:\\windows\\explorer.exe"));
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => process4 = Process.Start("C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Audition CC\\Adobe Audition CC.exe"));

        InitializeComponent();

    }



   public static void MainWindow2()
    {
        int f = 23;
        int g = 25;

        MessageBox.Show("f + g = " + "" + f + g);
    }


    private void button1_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hi");
    }




}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such ability to have an object property at the Namespace level..

```
namespace WpfApplication3

    {

    private object process5;
```